# SQL Injectable Webpage

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I'm creating a SQL Injection demo as a project for my class. I've created a login page but i cant seem to be able to inject it. Here is what I have written for the page. I have tried blind SQLi creating multiple clauses withing the username field. The only other thing I can think of is to use subqueries or to change my code to make it easier.

EDIT* Trying to Inject the username field *

```
 <?php // Check to see if there was a request method that is a post type
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
             // Check to see if username field is null
             if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {

                     // Connect to the server using credentials
                     $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','sqlcool1');
                     // If the connection was not successful
                     if (!$con){
                             echo 'OUCH';
                             die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
                     }
                     // Select the correct database from the server
                     $db = mysql_select_db('injectme',$con);
                     // Pass a sql query through the table to pull the user field that was entered in the form
                     // Return the results in an array
                     $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "' . $_POST['username'] . '"');
                     $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

                     // compare $row["password"] to $_post["password"]
                     //  if they match it's good: log them in
                     //  if not, they're beat: don't log them in

                     if ($_POST["username"] == $row[1] && $_POST["password"] == $row[2]) {
                     // do something to let them know that it worked
                     echo('<html>
                             <head>
                                     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=search.php">
                             </head>
                             <body>
                                     <p style="color:green">logged in</p>
                             </body>
                           </html>');
                     } else {
                             // do something to let them know it didn't work
                             echo('<p style="color: red">Invalid username or password.</p>');
                             echo('<form name="login" action="login.php" method="POST">
                                     Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                                     Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                                     <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit">
                                     <button type="submit" formaction="register.php">Register</button>
                                    </form>');
                                    }
                                    //Close the connected session with the server
                                    mysql_close($con);

                            } else {

                            // Repost Form
                            echo ('<p style="color: red"> No username / password provided.</p>');
                            echo('<form name="login" action="login.php" method="POST">
                                    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                                    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit">
                                    <button type="submit" formaction="register.php">Register</button>
                                    </form>');
                            }
            }
            else
            {
                            echo('<form name="login" action="login.php" method="POST">
                                 Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                                 Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                                 <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit">
                                 <button type="submit" formaction="register.php">Register</button>
                                 </form>');

            }
 ?>
```

Comment: how do you know that you can't seem to be able to inject it?

Comment: can you show, what usernames you already used? maybe you should let your site echo the query before/after executing it.

Comment: Posting `username=';DROP TABLE user;--` should about do it.

Comment: This has got to be the first time I've ever seen someone try and fail to create vulnerable code XD Well, the code *is* vulnerable, but it all depends on what you're trying to do. It should be noted that the ["classic" injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) won't work unless you actually allow multi-query calls.

Comment: I cant inject if from what I have tried. There is no results coming back. Just brings me to the invalid username or pass stage.

Comment: @Oonix: precisely what string are you injecting? Would you edit that information into your question?

Comment: Add `or exit(mysql_error())` to the end of `$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "' . $_POST['username'] . '"');` (just before the semi-colon). That'll show you what you want to see. Though, basically asking SO how to exploit a code isn't exactly a good idea

Comment: So if I don't allow multiple queries with mysqli_multi_query the classic injection wont work? What method would i try then?

Comment: @Malk It’s not possible to execute multiple statements with `mysql_query`.

Comment: @halfer No I didn't and I cant upvote anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To successfully exploit this vulnerability, you need to be able to inject some code such that the resulting SQL statement will return something that will pass the later test:

```
$_POST["username"] == $row[1] && $_POST["password"] == $row[2]
```

So the second column needs to be equal to the submitted username and the third row needs to be equal to the submitted password.

Now as the injection happens with the submitted username, you have a problem.

Because you cannot supply a username that fulfills both the *inject some data into the result set* aspect and the *inject a value for the username that is identical to the injected code that injects a value for the username* aspect.

The former is quite easy (assuming three columns in *user*):

```
username := '" UNION SELECT 1, "admin", "'
password := ''
```

This results in:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "" UNION SELECT 1, "admin", ""
```

However, the `$_POST["username"] == $row[1]` part remains unresolvable as you would need to make the second SELECT return the submitted username as username column value. And that’s just not possible.

Now if you just remove the `$_POST["username"] == $row[1]` it works fine.

Comment: @halfer It's absolutely not secure, see my answer.

Answer (score 12):

The code you have posted is entirely vulnerable and can be used to view the content of the entire database. One way to exploit it is with time based attack where you create an artificially long response time if a condition is true.

Consider the following username :

> " UNION SELECT (WHEN "A" = (SUBSTR(password, 1, 1)) THEN SLEEP(5) ELSE 1 END) AS username, 1 as password FROM user LIMIT 0, 1 --

If the response is longer than 5 seconds, you can know the value of the first character is "A" otherwise just test for an other character. After that you just have to repeat the same pattern for other position in the string until you have found all characters of the password. After that, you can just directly use the admin password. Since it requires a lot of queries those type of attack are often scripted.

If you want to read more about it, it's called [Blind SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to inject. If you are trying to inject a second query, this is not possible - the `mysql_query` function does not support multiple queries. From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Of course, it is still vulnerable to additional `WHERE` clause injections.